# Em quais momentos se faz necessário forçar a coleta de lixo em C# para um melhor desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, garbage-collector

Geralmente sempre tenho dúvida sobre o uso das funções para liberação de memória, em quais situações ela deve ser usada ou deverá sempre ser usada? E a minha realmente passará a ter um melhor desempenho?

Se possível alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de seu uso?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Nunca!

Ok, se você tiver um completo domínio do funcionamento da implementação atual do GC, estiver disposto pagar o preço se uma mudança ocorrer e puder melhorar quando houver uma mudança, pode ser que valha a pena fazer alguma coisa nesse sentido. Ou seja, só quando souber quando forçar a coleta lhe dará o "direito" de fazer isso. Em uma resposta superficial na internet, não te dará isto.

Se conseguir fazer testes exaustivos, se eles tiveram qualidade suficiente e provarem que a coleta manual não provoca perda de performance ou pelo menos que essas perdas não afeta a aplicação, então pode usar. Normalmente nem compensa o trabalho, na maior parte dos casos haverá perda. Nos casos onde a perda é tolerável, provavelmente a coleta manual não ajudará.

## Implementação atual

Na implementação atual do .NET chamar o coletor só piora as coisas, eu diria em 99,99% dos casos. Como ele é geracional, ele vai fazendo os dados de uma geração irem para outra artificialmente, e tudo o que você não quer é que os dados cheguem na última geração, a mais difícil de manipular e que causa os problemas que as pessoas dizem que o coletor de lixo tem, como as longas paradas, por exemplo.

Quando você faz a coleta de um lixo sem o "cesto" estar cheio há um desperdício de recurso. Quanto mais lixo, melhor o GC funciona, até porque ele trabalha com cópia dos dados "sobreviventes". Idealmente nenhum dado sobrevivente faria a coleta ser bem mais rápida. O GC do .NET é um dos melhores existentes do mercado e foi desenhado com cuidado para trazer os melhores resultados, é raro o programador ser mais esperto que ele.

Já vi dizerem que se você sabe que tudo está indo rápido para a Gen 2 (a última), então não é muito problemático. Sim, é verdade, mas por que isso está acontecendo? Provavelmente há um problema de *design* da aplicação.

## Onde é seguro usar

Há um caso onde pode usar quase seguramente. Quando for fazer um teste de performance e saiba que a memória não vai encher. Pode forçar só para ajudar garantir que o coletor não seja chamado dentro do teste. Ainda assim o ideal é assegurar que ele não foi chamado antes de confiar nos resultados. [É possível instrumentá-lo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Outros casos são usados para obter o mesmo efeito, evitar que uma coleta ocorra no meio de algo importante. Mas se é importante mesmo, talvez não deveria usar algo que possa ser coletado.

Há quem tente fazer isso entre renderização de *frame* de jogos para evitar congelamentos inesperados. Isso pode funcionar em certas circunstâncias, mas em geral é uma má ideia e não se costuma fazer isto. A implementação atual ajuda evitar paradas longas, por isso jogos são feitos com .NET sem problemas. Chamar a coleta provavelmente provocará mais paradas longas.

## Evitar a criação de lixo

O que dá pra fazer é minimizar o uso da memória gerenciada pelo GC, alocando mais coisas na pilha, ou criar *pools* de memória gerenciados pela aplicação, mesmo que eles estejam no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) gerenciado, assim só desaloca quando o programador quiser. Mas o trabalho que isto dá, a dificuldade de fazer certo, normalmente não compensa. Se isso é realmente necessário, quase sempre é melhor usar outra linguagem. Ou pelo menos pode usar um [*pool* de objetos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) padrão que agora tem no .NET.

Mas é preciso tomar cuidado, em geral o GC faz um ótimo trabalho. Há um [artigo mostrando o trabalho a mais que dá para tentar gerenciar as alocações por conta própria](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120184144/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/19/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-sixth-cut.aspx). E se fizer isso corre o risco de errar e acabar com um vazamento de memória.

O artigo mostra como o [Raymond Chen](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120184144/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/19/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-sixth-cut.aspx) fez um código em C++ que obteve uma performance excelente, mas deu muito trabalho e o código ficou complicado e quase ilegível, além de ter sido fácil cometer erro nele. Enquanto que o código C# teve performance próxima em um *port* simples da primeira versão do Raymond, sem sequer "idiomatizar" para o C#. Com pouca melhoria ficou mais próximo ainda.

Note que o C# usado era primitivo, não tinha *generics* que passou ajudar muito a performance agora. Hoje o resultado final poderia ser mais favorável ao C#. E se entendi bem o teste envolve até o tempo de carga do executável que claramente é pior no C# por causa do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) (agora temos a possibilidade de rodar sem JITter). E talvez poderia ter melhoras se aceitasse um código em C# menos legível, usando técnicas mas avançadas.

Gerenciar código manualmente certamente consegue melhor resultado que código gerenciado por GC, mas em grande parte dos casos não compensa. Em muitos casos o GC dará uma performance melhor que um código mais simples e ingênuo com gerenciamento manual. Para tudo existem exceções.

## Referências

- [Informação adicional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973837(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Um [artigo mais autoritativo](https://web.archive.org/web/20160209223913/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx).
- [Outro artigo](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114052546/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx) dele.
- Tem quem tentou, mas preferiu [outras abordagens](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector) do que chamar a coleta. Este aqui evita muita coleta, mas tem gente que domina o assunto profundamente fazendo isto.
- [Pergunta no Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/276585/389) que dá mais detalhes. Alguns dos exemplos mostrados são muito otimistas e eu não confiaria nisto sem testar. Minha experiência é que os casos citados não costumam se beneficiar de coleta manual.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótimo trabalho @bigown, esta resposta diz tudo, ja passei por problemas seríssimos ao utilizar o GC.Collect sem avaliar o impacto do mesmo. Essa resposta ajudará e muito toda a comunidade de desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: Pelo que o que entendi sobre o que foi exposto aqui, é que, eu nunca faça a chamada do GC manualmente ? Só, que andei pesquisando sobre o consumo de memória quando é utilizado ReportViewer e não vejo uma caminho a seguir. Tem um exemplo para que eu posso me basear ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias Chamar o GC só piora a situação. Precisa resolver o problema que está causando isso, que eu não sei qual é.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar outros caminhos para resolver.