# Impacto do Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

O projeto aqui da empresa é feito em *Windows Forms* e não gerenciamos muito bem a memoria, pois é um sistema legado que tem vários anos rodando.

Atualmente estamos enfrentando problemas com falta de memoria nos computadores onde roda o sistema pelo fato do consumo de memoria quando o sistema está rodando ser muito alto.

Tenho dúvidas quanto ao uso do *GC*, pois comecei a colocar em quase todos os lugares, mas parei para pensar e não sei se é a melhor forma, ainda mais projetos em *Windows Forms*.

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Em que momentos é bom limpar a memoria?
2. O momento ideal é quando abrir e fechar a tela?
3. Em todos os botões da tela?
4. Quais problemas podem ser causados com o uso excessivo do GC?

Como eu poderia resolver esses erros de falta de memoria?

Comment: "comecei a colocar em quase todos os lugares" o que isso quer dizer?

Comment: Empolguei e coloquei em botões e construtores, por exemplo... Onde achei que era critico, coloquei... Mas não sei se está certo.

Comment: Colocar o que?.

Comment: O GC.Collect();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Em que momentos é bom limpar a memoria?

Nunca. [Já respondi isso antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101).

> O momento ideal é quando abrir e fechar a tela?

Nunca!

> Em todos os botões da tela?

Nunca!

> Quais problemas podem ser causados com o uso excessivo do GC?

Pausas e perda de performance.

## Que mal pode causar em liberar a memória?

Essa é a real pergunta que deve ser feita. O problema está mais em fazer a liberação manual da memória do que em deixar sem fazer. As pausas serão mais frequentes e mais longas. Se havia um problema de memória, agora há um problema de gerenciamento dela. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque isso já está explicado na outra pergunta.

Pode ser que tenha um exagero na utilização na memória por arquitetura errada ou por falha em liberação. A liberação é automática, mas o programador tem que saber fazer. Ele não pode manter referências para os objetos.

## Real problema

Já vi casos de uma janela chamar outra que chama a primeira, aí vira um ciclo vicioso terrível. Mas a maioria dos casos nem é tão terrível, mas os objetos são mantidos vivos por mais tempo do que precisa.

Tem caso que deixam vazando mais tempo do que deveria. Tem objetos pre precisam de liberação explícita, [pelo menos usando o `using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101).

Eu vejo a maioria dos programadores fazendo códigos sem pensar em como elevai funcionar. Só querem ver o resultado. Isso não dá certo. É preciso planejamento. Sem saber como tudo funciona fica à mercê da coincidência. Pode dar certo ou não.

Não sei qual é o caso dessa aplicação, mas é possível que tenha sérios problemas de gerenciamento dos objetos. Talvez vá ter que fazer um *profiling*. tem ferramentas para isso:

- [CLR Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650691(v=pandp.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/)
- [JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx)
- [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)
- [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)
- [.NET Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/features/)
- [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Não dá para descartar a possibilidade de simplesmente a aplicação estar precisando de mais memória mesmo. Tem casos assim. Mas antes de investir no hardware precisa ter certeza que resolveu todos de software.

Agora tem melhores subsídios para começar pensar no problema certo e quem sabe fazer perguntas específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essas ferramentas se encarregariam de liberar a memoria de forma segura então?

Comment: Não. Nada vai magicamente resolver o problema. Elas ajudam você descobrir onde está o erro na aplicação para não começar no escuro. Normalmente nesses casos tem que reescrever muita coisa, rearquitetar a aplicação. Tem casos que é tão complicado que é melhor deixar pra lá e começar fazer de novo, desta vez entendendo todo funcionamento antes, caso contrário os problemas vão acontecer de novo. Claro que nem todos casos são tão terríveis assim.

Comment: Poxa entendi.. É porque tenho duas telas que quando há o uso excessivo delas, erros de falta de memoria começam a pipocar a ponto de fechar o sistema... Para resolver o erro temos que sair do sistema e abrir de novo para limpar tudo... Por isso achei que usar o GC nos construtores ajudaria a manter a memoria em um nível aceitável para não dar erro... Mas o melhor é não mexer manualmente com o GC e usar essas ferramentas para encontrar aonde está o gargalo né?

Comment: Só piora a situação. Se leu o que respondi antes verá que esse `GC.Collect()` é só para experimento, testes, não para uso em produção. Tem que ver quais objetos estão vivos mais tempo que o necessário. Nem sempre é fácil achar isso, porque a maioria dos programas são feitos sem pensar no todo. O primeiro passo é tomar consciência sobre tempo de vida de objetos. Não é só ir criando e esperar que uma hora eles sumam, Tem que garantir que as condições para isso se estabeleçam. Se as condições não acontecerem, o objeto não é liberado. Vive tendo vazamento de memória, poucos casos ficam aparentes.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de controlar o ciclo de vida do objeto? Um link onde eu possa me basear?

Comment: É técnica. É entender todo o funcionamento da memória, cada aspecto da aplicação. Não tem um *link*, tem milhares que precisam ser seguidos até entender tudo. Pelo menos falando genericamente. Claro que perguntas específicas sempre cabem.

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Isso pode ajudar um pouquinho: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101. Referências costumam ocorrer em grafos, o que é algo extremamente complicado quando se perde o controle. Por isso tem que saber onde cada objeto está referenciado e ter certeza que não está por engano. Não é só sair fazendo as coisas funcionarem, tem que saber se elas estão funcionando do jeito adequado.