# Preciso atribuir null à uma variável após o uso?

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, null, garbage-collector

Há a necessidade de atribuir `null` no objeto após o seu uso?

No exemplo abaixo logo após utilizar a lista eu tenho um método que demanda um grande tempo para ser executado. Eu preciso atribuir `null` à lista para otimizar a aplicação?

```
private void Exemplo()
    {
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = ObterClientes();

        foreach (Cliente cliente in listaClientes)
        {
            SalvarClientes(cliente);
        }

        // Preciso fazer isto?
        listaClientes = null;

        FazAlgumaCoisaDemorada();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nesse caso porque a variável é local, ela é destruída no final do método. Até poderia ser útil se essa lista for muito grande e se esse `FazAlgumaCoisaDemorada()` precisar de muita memória. Aí é provável que o GC seria acionado em algum momento no meio dele e o ideal é que ele possa liberar o máximo de memória possível. Mas isso é uma circunstância bem específica e rara.

Não faça "por via das dúvidas". Tem que testar e ver se tem vantagem e não causa outros problemas.

Na maior parte dos casos não afetará a performance. Curiosamente anular pode causar algum *delay* porque fica mais fácil haver uma coleta de lixo, mas será um *delay* benéfico pela natureza do GC do .NET.

Pode ser útil am algum caso onde a variável é estática ou faz parte de objeto que deve permanecer vivo por muito tempo e não quer manter vivo o objeto que ela se refere, aí é melhor liberar o objeto referenciado. Para fazer isso a forma mais simples é anular a variável.

Quase sempre quando precisa anular uma variável de instância ou estática, é porque algo foi mal arquitetado.

A liberação de memória não ocorre por ocasião do anulação da variável e sim quando o coletor de lixo resolver trabalhar. E por favor, [não force sua chamada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101)!

Answer (score 10):

A resposta é não, não tem efeito algum na performance.

Se a ideia é libertar memória, também não terá consequência, ela só será libertada quando o GC determinar que é a melhor altura para isso.
Tentar forçar a libertação de memória pode até provocar perdas de performance.