# Por que atribuir NULL em um ponteiro depois de um free?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Vejo em muitos códigos atribuirem `NULL` em um ponteiro logo após um `free`, tipo:

```
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Qual seria a vantagem disso?

Comment: Para referências, há uma discussão sobre no SOen: [it good practice to NULL a pointer after deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1931126/1452488)

Comment: Relacionada, acho eu: [Preciso atribuir null à uma variável após o uso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178812/5878)

Comment: Só evitar usar um endereço inválido de maneira inadvertida

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O seu segundo link é sobre C#, não C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trata-se de uma [boa prática](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Making_pointers_safer) que ajuda a evitar comportamentos inesperados e facilita bastante o tratamento de erros.

Após a chamada de `free(p)` o ponteiro `p` deixará de apontar para um endereço de memória válido, o que o torna um [`Ponteiro Selvagem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Manipular `Ponteiros Selvagens` **quase sempre** causa o [`Comportamento Indefinido`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) do programa.

Acontece que em `C`, não é possível determinar se um ponteiro trata-se ou não de um `Ponteiro Selvagem`.

"Forçar" o ponteiro que acabou de sofrer `free()` para `NULL` garante que não haverá `Ponteiros Selvagens` dentro do seu escopo, o que certamente vai facilitar a depuração e o controle de erros no seu programa.

Repare que inicializar ponteiros com `NULL` também faz parte da **mesma** ideia, pois o mesmo pode acontecer com um [`Ponteiro não Inicializado`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default/1910875)

A boa prática seria algo como:

```
void foobar( void )
{
    char * p = NULL;

    /* ... */

    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    /* ... */

    if( p == NULL )
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Isso depende muito do contexto onde é usado. Em especial o ponteiro após o `free` não é utilizável. Com o valor `NULL`, ele é utilizável. Por exemplo:

```
while (p != NULL) {
    // Um monte de código usando p aqui.

    if (alguma coisa) {
        free(p);
        p = NULL;
    }
}
```

Enfim, se a variável do ponteiro puder ser de alguma forma referenciada depois do `free`, faz sentido que `NULL` seja atribuído a ela para evitar referência a algo que não existe mais. O valor `NULL` pode ser testado, enquanto que um ponteiro inválido não pode.