# Esse trecho do código é redundante?

Tags: c, c++, estrutura-de-dados

Recentemente fiz uma prova em C em que tinha que completar um código de remover itens de uma fila, segue o código com a resposta considerada correta destacada:

```
typedef struct No {
  int dado;
  struct No *proximo;
};

typedef struct Fila {
  struct No *inicio;
  struct No *fim;
}; 

struct Fila *filaDePosts;

int filaRemover(){
 struct No* ptr_no = fila->inicio;
 int dado;

 if (ptr_no != NULL) {
    **fila->inicio = ptr_no->proximo;**
    **ptr_no->proximo = NULL;**
    dado = ptr_no->dado;
    free(ptr_no);
    return dado;
 }
}
```

No trecho do código `ptr_no->proximo = NULL;`, considerando que logo abaixo eu executo o comando `free(ptr_no);` que já vai liberar a memória alocada para a `struct ptr_no` e suas variáveis internas, é redundante e desnecessário anular o valor?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Por que atribuir NULL em um ponteiro depois de um free?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304535/82711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, parece redundante, está mudando um dado que não é usado depois em um objeto que logo será destruído.

Aproveitando poderia ter declarado `dado` direto no seu uso e teria um código menos redundante. E poderia ter usado um tipo no `typedef` para evitar a redundância de usar `struct`.

```
typedef struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *proximo;
} No;

typedef struct {
    No *inicio;
    No *fim;
} Fila;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Simplification.c).

No código também não precisa mais usar `struct`.