# Alterar atributos de classe passada como parâmetro para outra classe

Tags: c++

Existem duas classes, `classa` e `classb`, onde é passado como parâmetro para a `classb` uma instância da `classa` e posteriormente é feita a tentativa de alterar um parâmetro da `classa` através da `classb`, porém sem sucesso, por que isso não funciona?

Código de teste:

```
#include <iostream>

class CLASSA
{
public:
    int attribute = 10;

    void change(int a) {
        this->attribute = a;
    }
};

class CLASSB
{
public:
    CLASSA *otherclass;

    CLASSB(CLASSA classa) {
        this->otherclass = &classa;
    }

    void changeotherclass() {
        this->otherclass->change(2);
    }
};

CLASSA  classa;
CLASSB  classb(classa);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    classb.changeotherclass();

    std::cout << classa.attribute;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C++ os argumentos são, por defeito, passados por valor ou seja a função que recebe o argumento tem acesso a uma cópia da variável e não a variável em si. A cópia da variável é destruida no fim da execução da função. Isso significa que, quando voçê faz:

```
CLASSB(CLASSA classa) {
    this->otherclass = &classa;
}
```

O ponteiro `otherclass` passa a apontar para uma variável temporária que será destruída no fim da execuçao do construtor. E como consequência, o método

```
void changeotherclass() {
    this->otherclass->change(2);
}
```

escreve numa área da mémoria que pertencia a um objeto que já foi destruido (isso se não me engano resulta em comportamento indefinido).

A solução seria pegar o endereço do objeto. Por exemplo, em `CLASSB`:

```
CLASSB(CLASSA* classa) {
   this->otherclass = classa;
}
```

E passar o endereço como argumento:

```
CLASSB  classb(&classa);
```

É recomendado que sempre inicialize um ponteiro.

```
CLASSA *otherclass = nullptr;
```

Comment: Muito grato. Por que essa recomendação? Qual o risco de não inicializar ponteiros?

Comment: Simples: você não teria como checar se ponteiro é inválido, porque ele seria inicializado com um endereço aleatório. Tem [uma pergunta aqui que fala do mesmo assunto] (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304535/por-que-atribuir-null-em-um-ponteiro-depois-de-um-free). Lembrando que em C usa-se `NULL` e não `nullptr`, mas são quase a mesma coisa.