# Como liberar memoria apôs realizar certa tarefa?

Tags: c#, winforms, memória

Em uma certa tarefa, tenho que carregar 6 fotos em 6 `PictureBox`, para isso utilizo o método abaixo:

```
 private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao carregar foto
    {
        OpenFileDialog carrega_foto = new OpenFileDialog();
        carrega_foto.Filter = "jpg|*.jpg";

        if (carrega_foto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if(pic1 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic1 = 1;
            }
            else  if(pic2 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox2.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic2 = 1;
            }
            else if (pic3 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox3.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic3 = 1;
            }
            else if (pic4 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox4.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic4 = 1;
            }
            else if (pic5 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox5.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic5 = 1;
            }
            else if (pic6 == 0)
            {
                pictureBox6.ImageLocation = carrega_foto.FileName;

                pictureBox6.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                pic6 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Então, pego as fotos, redimensiono elas, trasnformo em um `array` de `byte[]` e salvo no banco de dados, com o metodo abaixo:

```
            try
            {
                PictureBox[] List_Picture = { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6 };

                foreach (PictureBox Pic in List_Picture)
                {
                    if (Pic.ImageLocation != null)
                    {
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

                        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 10L);

                        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

                        var codec = ObterCodec(Pic.Image.RawFormat);

                        Pic.Image.Save(stream, codec, myEncoderParameters);                            

                        byte[] Bfoto = stream.ToArray();

                        Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM Cad_Foto = new Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM();

                        Cad_Foto.Cad_Foto_Anal_Crm(textEdit8.Text, Bfoto);

                        Pic.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro, Contate o adiministrador!" + "\n" + error, "Salvar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

então, realizando um `debug` vi que quando carrego as fotos, é utilizado bastante memoria para isso, ate ai tudo bem..

Porem, depois que eu salvo a foto no banco, como faço para liberar essa memoria utilizada?

tentei usar o metodo `Dispose` mas não deu certo!
Oque acontece e que se tento executar essa tarefa novamente, é gerado a exceção abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basicamente é isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101. Esse código está criando vários recursos que nunca são liberados. Tem que ver a documentação de todos os objetos usados para saber quais precisam de liberação, ou usar alguma ferramenta que indique isto para você, como o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Na verdade esse código tem vários outros pequenos problemas.

Comment: @bigown me corrija se estiver errado, então oque posso fazer é, utilizar do metodo `using` e `dispose` e aguardar que o sistema "recolha o lixo"  sozinho?

Comment: O `using`, o `Dispose()` como você usou não será executado se houver uma exceção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, com o seguinte código:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) 
{
   pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
   pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```

Refencia: [Como definir imagens em tempo de execução (Windows Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t94wdca5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Uitilize o Garbage Collection:

```
GC.Collect();
```

mais informações:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Não, isso só agrava a situação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101

Comment: interessante, obrigado