# Garbage collector é automático?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collector

Notei que minha aplicação estava consumindo deliberadamente a memória mesmo após o fim do processamento, mesmo finalizando tudo que foi iniciado então chamei o  `GC.Collect();` e a memoria foi liberada.

Aí me veio a duvida, o *garbage collector* não deveria ser automático?, Se sim, existem 'coisas' que ele não coleta ou isso pode ser um erro da minha aplicação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele é automático e [isso que você fez não deve ser feito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101). O problema é que na verdade ou não havia pressão por memória ou você [não está liberando a memória como está pensando que está](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101).

Não sei o método que usou para verificar, mas o fato de indicar que há memória comprometida com a aplicação não quer dizer que esteja sendo usada, e o que aconteceu foi descomprometer o que não estava sendo usado, o que é algo inócuo e até há uma ínfima perda em fazer isso.

O GC age quando é necessário, ele sabe fazer isso muito bem. Em algumas raras aplicações é preciso controlar isso de forma mais específica e não é tarefa fácil. Mas pelo menos é segura, ao contrário de linguagens não gerenciadas que além de ser extremamente difícil, corre riscos. O GC só age quando é solicitada uma alocação no *heap* e não tem espaço em uma das gerações.

Posso te garantir que teve um monte de coleta que você nem percebeu. Teria que monitorar o GC para ver as coletas que ocorreram.

Tem uma [API para isto](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/556-2/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Lista de eventos que ele gera](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/garbage-collection-etw-events?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[CLR Profiler](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/clrprofiler).

[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[image: Process Explorer]